# Edit folder name option not available, and I cannot upload file

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

It appears that there is no option to edit the folder name in the Firebase Storage. Will this option be added eventually?
And also, when I click on "UPLOAD FILE" it does not seem to work, at least for me; I'm wondering if I'm missing something.
Thanks.

Comment: Do any errors shows in the developer console on your browser when you try to upload?

Comment: Franck, no errors show in my browser. Nothing show when I click. I would expect a popup to select the folder, but it doesn't show up at all.

Comment: I've tried with Firefox, everything seems to be fine. I can upload my files to the storage. The issue is with Google Chrome. I've tried to change the settings by allowing any popups, but it's still not working. That's odd!

Comment: I just uploaded an image through Chrome 51 without any problems. Did you try in an incognito window, disabling any popups, etc.?

Comment: @M'Boulas following up on this--have you tried disabling extensions/running this in an incognito window? Do you happen to be running Windows 10?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, guys! @Frank I've tried in an incognito window, allowed popups, but no change!

Comment: @Mike yes, I'm running Windows 10. But I don't have this issue with Firefox though; which is really odd.

Comment: Yeah, we've only seen this on Chrome 51 on Windows 10. We're trying to get a Windows 10 machine (surprisingly hard to find one) to repro this and see what's wrong.

Comment: @Mike I also have Chrome 51. I hope you get a chance to look into this. Your help is really appreciated.